# codeigniter 4 rest api error 501 show action not implemented

Tags: codeigniter-4, codeigniter-restserver

I'm trying to create a simple REST server using CI 4 based on [this article](https://remotestack.io/codeigniter-rest-api-development-example-tutorial/). this is my code:

app/Controllers/Barang.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\Model_Barang;


class Barang extends ResourceController
{

    use ResponseTrait;

    // get multiple data
    public function index()
    {
        $apiModel = new Model_Barang();
        $data = $apiModel->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->findAll();
        return $this->respond($data);
    }

    // get single data
    public function getBarang($id = null)
    {
        $apiModel = new Model_Barang();
        $data = $apiModel->where('id', $id)->first();
        if($data){
            return $this->respond($data);
        }else{
            return $this->failNotFound('Barang tidak ditemukan.');
        }
    }

    // the other functions for create, update, delete

}
```

app/Models/Model_Barang.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Model_Barang extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'barang';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = [
      'nama', 
      'harga',
      'jumlah',
      'kode_supplier'
    ];
}
```

when I test it using Postman with method GET on this URL `http://localhost:8080/barang/` it works fine (it shows all the data in the `barang` table), but when I use `http://localhost:8080/barang/1` it suddenly returns an error saying

```
{
    "status": 501,
    "error": 501,
    "messages": {
        "error": "\"show\" action not implemented."
    }
}
```

I know that according to the code, I should use `http://localhost:8080/barang/getBarang/1` instead, and when I tried using `getBarang/` it DID work.. but isn't that not *RESTful*? also, the article said that I can use the url without `getBarang/` to get a specific data.. am I doing something wrong? or is this just a CI4's cons?

Comment: [The CI docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/restful.html) have some info about setting up a REST resource. I guess that you have done somethnig like `$routes->resource('barang')`.  As the docs show, that will set up a GET route for `barang/x`, which maps to a controller method like `show()`.  And as your error says, you have not created that method yet.  Who knows what the tutorial author was trying to do, but the docs are pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Explanation:

```php
$routes->resource('barang');
```

[Resource Routes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/restful.html#resource-routes)

The above line of code in `app/Config/Routes.php` is equivalent to:

```php
// Equivalent to the following auto-generated routes:

$routes->get('barang/new',             'Barang::new');
$routes->post('barang',                'Barang::create');
$routes->get('barang',                 'Barang::index');
$routes->get('barang/(:segment)',      'Barang::show/$1'); 
$routes->get('barang/(:segment)/edit', 'Barang::edit/$1');
$routes->put('barang/(:segment)',      'Barang::update/$1');
$routes->patch('barang/(:segment)',    'Barang::update/$1');
$routes->delete('barang/(:segment)',   'Barang::delete/$1');
```

Calling `http://localhost:8080/barang/1` in postman corresponds to this route match:

```php
$routes->get('barang/(:segment)',      'Barang::show/$1');
```

`'Barang::show/$1'` means that CodeIgniter is going to try to call the `show(...)` method in the `Barang` controller passing `(:segment)` which in your case is `1` as the first method argument.

Since your controller is **missing** the `show(...)` method, CodeIgniter complains about it with an error below:

```php
{
    "status": 501,
    "error": 501,
    "messages": {
        "error": "\"show\" action not implemented."
    }
}
```

##### Solution:

To resolve this, you have 2 options/solutions. Whichever solution fits your needs, you will be able to *get a single data set* in postman by using `GET http://localhost:8080/barang/1`

##### Solution 1:

Simply rename the controller method:

**App\Controllers\Barang.php**

Instead of:

```php
// ...
public function getBarang($id = null) ❌
// ...
```

Use this:

```php
// ...
public function show($id = null) ✅
// ...
```

##### Solution 2:

If for some reason you wish to maintain the method name `getBarang(...)` to act as the equivalent of the expected method `show(...)`, inform the `$routes->resource(...);` **not** to auto-create the `show(...)` method route definition and later manually define it on your own. I.e:

[Limit the Routes Made](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/restful.html#limit-the-routes-made)

**app/Config/Routes.php**

Instead of:

```php
// ...
$routes->resource('barang'); ❌
// ...
```

Use this:

```php
// ...
$routes->resource('barang', ['except' => 'show']); ✅
$routes->get('barang/(:segment)',      'Barang::getBarang/$1');
// ...
```

Comment: thanks! I accidentally came to think your first solution last night but I forgot to put an answer here. also, I think I'm too lazy to put together an answer as neat and thorough as yours